# Can’t guess python-indent-offset - delete warning when local file variable

Tags: indentation, python

I have this comment that I write in my python file

```
# -*- Mode: Python; tab-width: 8; indent-tabs-mode: nil; python-indent-offset: 2 -*-
# vim:set et sts=4 ts=4 tw=80:
```

But when I load a python file, there's the following messages:
`Can’t guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4`

However, it set the indentation to the value precised (I tried with 99). But it still display the message. It seems that it tried first to guess the indent, then it read the local variable.

I don't want to set `python-guess-indent-offset` to nil (for files which aren't mine) but I would like to get ride of this warning if possible.

Does anyone have an idea how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is controlled by the `python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose` variable.

Since the variable is file-local, you should be able to disable it globally if you put the following in your `init.el`:

```
   (setq python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose nil)
```

Then do what you're already doing, that is, put the following at the top of your personal files:

```
# -*- mode: python; python-indent-offset: 2 -*-
```

---

To discover this, I did the following:

1. `C-h e` to see the `*Messages*` buffer
2. Copied part of the error message text
3. `C-h f python-mode`
4. Clicked the link for `python.el`
5. Searched for the error message in `python.el` using `C-s using defaults`
6. Found that the message was called in the following block:

   ```
       (when python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose
         (message "Can't guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: %s"
                  python-indent-offset))))))))
   ```

From there, I looked at the documentation for `python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose` using `C-h v`.